# Módulo rewrite em .htaccess [separar por pasta]

Tags: htaccess

Galera eu tenho duas pastas, quando eu adiciono a função ele pega somente a primeira, por exemplo:

```
RewriteRule ^atacado/(.*)/(.*) atacado/index.php?estado=$1&cidade=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^mercado/(.*)/(.*) mercado/index.php?estado=$1&cidade=$2 [NC,L]
```

no html está assim:

```
/atacado/SP/São+Paulo
/mercado/SP/São+Paulo
```

ao clicar no /atacado funciona corretamente, agora quando clico em MERCADO o css quebra, vira uma bagaça louca, já verifiquei os headers e estão todos absolutos.
o que poderia ser?

Comment: Eu editei a resposta dá uma olhada http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/180099/3635

Comment: A resposta lhe resolveu o problema? Poderia informar o que houve?

Answer (score 0):

A pasta CSS não vai funcionar se não fizer os apontamentos corretos, recomendo que tente usar o endereço em todos CSSs com `/` na frente, assim:

```
<link href="/css/estilo1.css">
<link href="/css/estilo2.css">
<link href="/css/estilo3.css">
```

Ou caminho absoluto:

```
<link href="http://site/css/estilo1.css">
<link href="http://site/css/estilo2.css">
<link href="http://site/css/estilo3.css">
```

Lembre-se a pasta CSS tem que estar fora da pasta `./atacado`, se estiver dentro você vai se atrapalhar ao usar a pasta `./mercado`, se você quer manter dentro da pasta `./atacado` não der certo você pode tentar usar a tag `<base>` dentro do `./mercado/index.php` assim:

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="/atacado/">
...
```

Claro que se você está usando um `include ...;` para adicionar o `header` talvez seja melhor usar o caminho absoluto como citei lá em cima.

---

<s>Provavelmente é porque você criou uma pasta chamada `./atacado`, note também que você adicionou as pastas na reescrita</s>

```
atacado/index.php?estado=$1&cidade=$2 [NC,L] <-- antes do index.php tem a pasta atacado
mercado/index.php?estado=$1&cidade=$2 [NC,L] <-- antes do index.php tem a pasta mercado
```

Provavelmente a pasta `./mercado` ou o arquivo em `./mercado/index.php` não existe, creio que na verdade você queira apontar tudo para index.php que está na mesma pasta que o .htaccess, então o correto seria:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^atacado/(.*)/(.*) index.php?estado=$1&cidade=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^mercado/(.*)/(.*) index.php?estado=$1&cidade=$2 [NC,L]
```

Agora se realmente você quer apontar para uma pasta chamada mercado e para uma pasta chamada atacado, então deve ter certeza que ambas existem e que estão em letras minusculas (se for like-unix), a estrutura esperada pelo seu `.htaccess` deve ser esta:

```
./
├── .htaccess
├── atacado/
|    └── index.php
└── mercado/
     └── index.php
```

Também deve conferir se não há nenhum outro .htaccess dentro das pastas "mercado" e "atacado" e também conferir se não esqueceu de adicionar `RewriteEngine On`